# RTSP streaming service using cloudfront and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to create a distribution network for the mp3 files of my amazon S3 bucket. I managed to achieve it using aws Cloudfront using RTMP protocol. But as android has no native support for RTMP, i am exploring the idea of making it using RTSP protocol.Can some one help in figuring out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RTSP` is stateful as it maintains a connection trough `RTCP`, requires multiple ports and you will have issues with firewall traversal. Plus, if you want to take advantage of S3 you should use instead a `HTTP` streaming protocol, unless you want to stream the `mp3` files directly via progressive download.

The are two alternatives: `HLS` and `DASH`, with `HLS` being the most used format at the moment.

Android `4.x+` has native support for `HLS`, it works on iOS out of the box since it's made by Apple and on desktops it works natively on Safari 6+ and all other browsers with a Flash fallback. There are many web players available, the most noteworthy being JWPlayer (paid) or clappr (open-source).

The Amazon Elastic Transcoder supports `HLS` transcoding and you can also use an open-source solution like `ffmpeg`.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: Thanks of the reply. I have already made HLS streaming available. Thanks for confirming it.